# List to Numpy Array and Reshape (Dimension Problem)

Tags: python, list, numpy, reshape

I have a list from appending 2 numpy array.

```
mylist=

[array([[5.45, 2.97, 6.25],
        [7.27, 5.28, 4.18]]),
array([[4.54, 2.06, 2.53],
       [7.2, 5.28, 1.29]])]
```

I would like to re-create numpy array from this list as follow:

```
array([[5.45, 2.97, 6.25,4.54, 2.06, 2.53]],
       [7.27, 5.28, 4.18,7.2, 5.28, 1.29]])
```

I tried np.array(mylist).reshape(2,6), but the result is not as my aim.

Comment: `np.column_stack(mylist)`

Comment: Or `np.hstack` (or `np.concatenate(mylist, axis=1)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [145]: alist = [np.array([[5.45, 2.97, 6.25],
     ...:         [7.27, 5.28, 4.18]]),
     ...:         np.array([[4.54, 2.06, 2.53],
     ...:         [7.2, 5.28, 1.29]])]

In [147]: np.hstack(alist)
Out[147]: 
array([[5.45, 2.97, 6.25, 4.54, 2.06, 2.53],
       [7.27, 5.28, 4.18, 7.2 , 5.28, 1.29]])
```

which is just a compact way of calling

```
In [148]: np.concatenate(alist, axis=1)
Out[148]: 
array([[5.45, 2.97, 6.25, 4.54, 2.06, 2.53],
       [7.27, 5.28, 4.18, 7.2 , 5.28, 1.29]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = np.array(mylist)
arr

>>> [[[5.45, 2.97, 6.25],
      [7.27, 5.28, 4.18]],

     [[4.54, 2.06, 2.53],
      [7.2 , 5.28, 1.29]]]
```

you need to swap the first and second axis before reshaping

```
brr = arr.transpose([1, 0, 2]).reshape(2, -1)
brr

>>> [[5.45, 2.97, 6.25, 4.54, 2.06, 2.53],
     [7.27, 5.28, 4.18, 7.2 , 5.28, 1.29]]
```